# Auto-generate custom JavaDoc comments for overriden methods

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm looking for the way to enhance readability of my Java sources and would like to add
following JavaDoc comment to all overridden methods

```
/** Overrides {@link com.org.pkg.MyInterface#myMethod}. */
@Override
protected boolean myMethod() {
    ...
}
```

This will be handy when class implements multiple interfaces as well as overrides some class methods. It is not always clear at first sight "what is what".

The question is - is there some command-line tool or IDE plugin (IDEA, NetBeans, Eclipse) which can automate this?

Comment: Most IDEs nowadays make this information visible already. For example, hovering over an arrow to the left of the method signature in Eclipse will reveal a tip showing what method is overridden. So are you sure this will make your java source more readable? Besides that, most IDEs also have templates to make it easy to auto-add this information on new methods. Are you talking about adding this after-the-fact to an existing code base?

Comment: I second what StriplingWarrior says. The IDE will show you what methods are overridden. Eclipse will show the inherited Javadocs when hovered over the method. I would argue that adding unnecessary docs just clutters the code, making it **less** readable.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about support provided in IDE's, however (1) there are numerous use cases outside of IDE - like printed version of source code or code copy/pasted to some wikies and (2) having to hover over 10 methods takes really more time then having needed 1-line information right in front of my eyes.

Comment: And yes - i more care about "adding this after-the-fact to an existing code base" (most probably using command line tool). This is a more universal solution - different people use different IDE with completely different system of plugins and different set of provided functionality. I personally prefer NetBeans and I did not notice such support there :(.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse generates that comment automatically for you when you create the methods

The default template is

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * ${see_to_overridden}
 */
```

where  ${see_to_overridden} is turned into  @see com.org.pkg.MyInterface#myMethod

You can change the template in windows->preferences->java->code style->code templates

to add it to an existing method , just type /* and return above the method

I don t know anyway to do that in batch however